# sorting based on two parameters, using a closure

Tags: javascript

I have a list of objects. I want to sort it based on two parameters. I created a sort function, but I'm sure it can be refactored. Any suggestions?

```js
const scoreArray = [{
    "code": "NOR",
    "g": 11,
    "s": 5,
    "b": 10
  },

  {
    "code": "RUS",
    "g": 13,
    "s": 11,
    "b": 9
  },
  {
    "code": "NED",
    "g": 8,
    "s": 7,
    "b": 9
  }
]

var getCompareFunction = (primaryKey, secondaryKey) => {
  return ((primaryKey, secondaryKey) => {
    return (x, y) => {
      if (x[primaryKey] === y[primaryKey]) {
        if (x[secondaryKey] > y[secondaryKey]) {
          return -1
        } else if (x[secondaryKey] < y[secondaryKey]) {
          return 1
        } else {
          return 0
        }
      } else if (x[primaryKey] > y[primaryKey]) {
        return -1
      } else if (x[primaryKey] < y[primaryKey]) {
        return 1
      }
    }

  })(primaryKey, secondaryKey)
}



const compareFuncHolder = getCompareFunction('s', 'b')

scoreArray.sort(compareFuncHolder);

console.log(scoreArray);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [partial application](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/curry-or-partial-application-8150044c78b8) without [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE). In addition, you can use the difference from the primaries, and if the result is `0` take the difference from the secondaries using [short-circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-circuit_evaluation):

```js
const scoreArray = [{"code":"NOR","g":11,"s":5,"b":10},{"code":"RUS","g":13,"s":11,"b":9},{"code":"NED","g":8,"s":7,"b":9}]

const getCompareFunction = (primaryKey, secondaryKey) => (x, y) =>
    y[primaryKey] - x[primaryKey] || y[secondaryKey] - x[secondaryKey]

const compareFuncHolder = getCompareFunction('b', 's')

scoreArray.sort(compareFuncHolder);

console.log(scoreArray);
```

If you need to compare string values as well as numbers, you can use a < or >, and cast the result of the comparison to a number (`false` -> 0, `true` -> 1) using the +/- operators (see [bergi's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52572200/sorting-based-on-two-parameters-using-a-closure/52572299?noredirect=1#comment92081782_52572299)):

```js
const scoreArray = [{"code":"NOR","g":11,"s":5,"b":10},{"code":"RUS","g":13,"s":11,"b":9},{"code":"NED","g":8,"s":7,"b":9}]

const compare = (x, y) => +(x > y) || -(y > x);

const getCompareFunction = (primaryKey, secondaryKey) => (x, y) =>
    compare(y[primaryKey], x[primaryKey]) || compare(y[secondaryKey], x[secondaryKey])

const compareFuncHolder = getCompareFunction('code', 's')

scoreArray.sort(compareFuncHolder);

console.log(scoreArray);
```

Comment: This doesn’t work if the values being compared are strings with non-digit characters, as `-` with such a string is always `NaN`.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall - indeed. Added a solution that uses localeCompare for this cases.

Comment: Why make it so complicated to compare arbitrary values? Using `<`/`>` is totally fine (and fast). You can use `compare = (a, b) => +(a>b)||-(b>a)` if you want to shorten the `if`/`else` statements.

Comment: @Bergi - I was looking for something like that. Between the ternary and localeCompare, the latter for better. However, this one wins.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a nested approach of closure and a short circuit by iterating the keys and their return values for sorting.

This works for an arbitrary count of compare keys.

```js
const
    genCompareFn = (...keys) => (v => (a, b) => keys.some(k => v = (a[k] > b[k]) - (a[k] < b[k])) && v)(),
    scoreArray = [{ code: "NOR", g: 11, s: 5, b: 10 }, { code: "RUS", g: 13, s: 11, b: 9 }, { code: "NED", g: 8, s: 7, b: 9 }],
    compareFn1 = genCompareFn('s', 'b'),
    compareFn2 = genCompareFn('b', 'g');
    
console.log(scoreArray.sort(compareFn1));
console.log(scoreArray.sort(compareFn2));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```